# Serialised SQL in Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a client that has used Woocommerce/Wordpress to build a basic ecomm store. In the database, all order items are serialised. For example:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:2:"id";s:2:"25";s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:10:"The Hobbit";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:9:"item_meta";a:0:{}s:13:"line_subtotal";s:4:"17.5";s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";s:4:"1.84";s:10:"line_total";s:4:"17.5";s:8:"line_tax";s:4:"1.84";s:9:"tax_class";s:0:"";}}
```

Not being a db genius - why would any data be serialised? Is there a benefit to this? Additionally, is it possible to unserialise SQL to retrieve the individual values within that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't serialized SQL, it's serialized data, in a format that looks like it came out of PHP's `serialize()` function. You could run it through `unserialize()` via PHP, but there's not really a reliable way to do this in raw SQL.

In this case, this appears to save schemaless data (i.e. data that may or may not be present for a particular record, potentially arbitrary in nature) into a database.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. If I was wanting to create a CSV of the database, can you use PHP to unserialise it and separate those values?

Comment: The problem is, serialized data like this is used because it doesn't fit neatly in a strict set of columns. You could certainly try to process it with PHP and generate a CSV, but you'd likely wind up with hundreds of columns, many of which would be empty for a lot of the rows.